# why from geometry is the ratio of arc equal to the ratio of the radii in two circles

Tags: geometry

why is the ratio of arc lengths equal to  the ratio of radii between two circles in geometry. I asked previously why are the ratio of arc length equal to the ratio of angle measures and I think these two questions are related.

I have scoured the web and any geometry textbooks I could get a hold of but I am unsuccessful. I welcome all comment. Thanks.

Comment: Because the shapes are similar (this is just a definition).

Comment: Because pi is a constant?  Arc length = 2 radius x pi x interior angle/360.  The only thing that changes is the radius so the arcs are proportional to the radii.

Answer (score 1):

The answer relies on the definition of similarity. If you have 2 similar triangles, then the ratio of corresponding side lengths is always constant. This is because the triangles are similar.

Now, all circles are similar (again, by definition). The only thing that differs between any 2 circles is the radii. You can measure several things in a circle: diameter, angles, arc lengths, etc. Because of similarity, comparing any of these measurements between 2 circles is the same as comparing their radii.

Answer (score 0):

The circumference of a circle is $2 \pi r $. The measure of an arc is a portion of that.  If the internal angle of the arc is a proportion of 360 degrees, the length of an arc will be that proportion of $2 \pi r $.

Call that proportion  B so the length of the arc is $B 2\pi r $.

Now imagine another circle and another arc.  This arc is the same B proportion to the circumference.  The only difference is the radius.  Let's say it is r2.  So the arc is $B 2 \pi r2$.

So arc/arc2 =$B 2\pi r/B 2\pi r2 = r/r2$.